# Addressing a non-integer address, and sse

Tags: c, pointers, x86, sse, memory-alignment

I am trying to accelerate my code using SSE, and the following code works well.
Basically a `__m128` variable should point to 4 floats in a row, in order to do 4 operations at once.

This code is equivalent to computing `c[i]=a[i]+b[i]` with `i` from `0` to `3`.

```
float *data1,*data2,*data3
// ... code ... allocating data1-2-3 which are very long.
__m128* a = (__m128*) (data1);
__m128* b = (__m128*) (data2);
__m128* c = (__m128*) (data3);
*c = _mm_add_ps(*a, *b);
```

However, when I want to shift a bit the data that I use (see below), in order to compute `c[i]=a[i+1]+b[i]` with `i` from `0` to `3`, it crashes at execution time.

```
__m128* a = (__m128*) (data1+1); // <-- +1
__m128* b = (__m128*) (data2);
__m128* c = (__m128*) (data3);
*c = _mm_add_ps(*a, *b);
```

My guess is that it is related to the fact that `__m128` is 128 bits and by `float` data are 32 bits. So, it may be impossible for a 128-bit pointer to point on an address that is not divisible by 128.

Anyway, do you know what the problem is and how I could go around it?

Comment: You have undefined behavior. A pointer to `float` is *not* the same as a pointer to `__m128`. Also, when you do `data1 + 1` it's the same thing as doing `&data1[1]`, have you really allocated more than one `float` and stored the pointer in `data1`?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of data into data1,data2,data3. They are well allocated.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, What is undedined behavior? I know that pointers to float and __m128 are different. That is why I cast. __mm128 should point to 4 floats in a row, in order to do all 4 operations at once on the cpu.

Comment: Okay, I was wrong about pointer casting and assignment. But can a `__m128` type really be misaligned like you do in your second example?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I have added some edits to make it more clear.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: For future reference, the only undefined behaviour (on compilers that support intrinsics at all), is dereferencing a `__m128*` whose alignment is less than `alignof(__m128) == 16`.  In ISO C, even creating an under-aligned pointer is UB, but the intrinsics API requires that behaviour to be well-defined so you can pass it to `loadu` / `storeu` intrinsics.  [Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](//stackoverflow.com/q/52112605) also points out that `__m128*` can alias anything (not just floats).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using implicit aligned loads/stores like this:

```
__m128* a = (__m128*) (data1+1); // <-- +1
__m128* b = (__m128*) (data2);
__m128* c = (__m128*) (data3);
*c = _mm_add_ps(*a, *b);
```

use explicit aligned/unaligned loads/stores as appropriate, e.g.:

```
__m128 va = _mm_loadu_ps(data1+1); // <-- +1 (NB: use unaligned load)
__m128 vb = _mm_load_ps(data2);
__m128 vc = _mm_add_ps(va, vb);
_mm_store_ps(data3, vc);
```

Same amount of code (i.e. same number of instructions), but it won't crash, and you have explicit control over which loads/stores are aligned and which are unaligned.

Note that recent CPUs have relatively small penalties for unaligned loads, but on older CPUs there can be a 2x or greater hit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that `a` ends up pointing to something that is not a `__m128`; it points to something that contains the last 96 bits of an `__m128` and 32 bits outside, which can be anything. It may be the first 32 bits of the next `__m128`, but eventually, when you arrive at the last `__m128` in the same memory block, it will be something else. Maybe reserved memory that you cannot access, hence the crash.

Comment: That might be true at the *end* of the array, so padding `a[]` with 1 extra element could make a `_mm_loadu_ps` safe instead of going off the end.  But that doesn't answer the question about why dereference faults on misalignment.